# Finding parameter names for binding stored procedure parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-10g, c#, parameter

For unit testing purposes I am attempting to call the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` procedure from `c#` using parameters that are bound by name. Since this `DBMS_OUTPUT` package seems to be a standard on Oracle databases, I am using it to test the code that I have written.

I have been able to successfully call `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE` with the `OraleCommand.BindByName` flag set to `true`. However, that is being called without passing any parameters. I have also been able to call a stored procedure that I made myself by passing a reference cursor bound by name.

When I attempt to call `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in a similar fashion I get the following message:

**Error Details**

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am specifying the bind name for the parameter as `item` according to how the procedure is defined in the 10g documentation for [DBMS_OUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105). The parameter type for `item` is defined as `VARCHAR2` and that is the type that is being passed to the procedure. When I set the `OracleCommand.BindByName` flag to false, I am able to call `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` with no problems.

Here is the code that I am using to run the query:

```
public bool ExecuteQuery(string procedureName, string[,] queryParameters, bool useReferenceCursor = false)
{
    bool returnStatus = false;

    if (ConnectionStatus() == false)
    {
        //message database connection was interrupted
        return false;
    }

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;

    cmd.Connection = databaseConnection;

    if (useReferenceCursor)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("output_reference_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    }

    for (int parameterSet = 0; parameterSet < queryParameters.GetLength(0); parameterSet++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            queryParameters[parameterSet, 0],
            OracleDbType.Varchar2,
            256,
            queryParameters[parameterSet, 1],
            ParameterDirection.Input
        );
    }

    if (ConnectionStatus() == false)
    {
        //message database connection was interrupted
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        queryDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        queryHasRows = queryDataReader.HasRows;
        returnStatus = true;
    }
    catch (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException error)
    {
        switch (error.Number)
        {
            case 6550:
                Console.WriteLine("The stored procedure specified doesn't exist.");
                DatabaseErrorMessage("The stored procedure doesn't exist. Make sure that the procedure has been properly compiled and that the names match.");
                break;
            default:
                throw error;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        queryHasRows = false;
        returnStatus = false;
    }

    return returnStatus;
}
```

Just for reference, we have decided to pass all parameters to the procedures that we write as `OracleDbType.Varchar2` and perform the type casting in the stored procedures that we define. The only exception to this would be reference cursors. I am also using Oracle's `ODP.net` for access since the Microsoft equivalent is obsolete.

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little bit more research and found the answer to the problem.

Even though the first parameter for `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is listed as `item` in the 10g documentation for DBMS_OUTPUT. The actual name for the parameter is `A`. You need to bind the name using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(A => 'random text')`.

The actual parameter names for stored procedures can be discovered using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    argument_name, 
    in_out, 
    data_type 
FROM 
    all_arguments 
WHERE 
    owner = 'SYS' --owner for said procedure
    AND package_name = 'DBMS_OUTPUT' --if procedure is in a package that name, null otherwise
    AND object_name = 'PUT_LINE' --procedure name
```

The values `SYS`, `DBMS_OUTPUT`, and `PUT_LINE` can be replaced with the values of the the stored procedure that you would like to look up.